# User authentication and verification for android app

Tags: android, security, user-interface, authentication

I think this may not be the right question for this forum, but I could not think of where else to post it.

However, here goes. I am creating a dating app in android. One of the major hurdles I am facing is user authentication and verification.

Put simply, how do I ensure that a user is who he/she really says he is? How do I prevent, or reduce people creating fake profiles on the app? One way to do this would be to force the user to connect with his facebook account, but again, fake facebook profiles can be created.

Is there any other good method to ensure user verification?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of, although not fool proof, would be when the user creates an account it sends them an email where they need to click a link. Clicking the link can ask for some confirmation of something, such as their chosen username and or the first name and last name etc. If they fill in this information from the email, they're probably legit and you can mark the account as active within the database. If after x number of days delete any accounts that have not been verified.

Comment: This would not prevent a user from creating multiple accounts through different email addresses. I want to prevent that. Any ideas?

Comment: There's not really a way you could prevent it. There'd be no way of knowing if its the same person or not if they are using completely different details